# declared global variable getting displayed undefined inside the function

Tags: javascript, closures, global-variables

When executing the following snippet getting data **undefined**. Data is declared above the function definition.Not understanding how it become **undefined**.

```
var data =100;

test();

function test() {

console.log('Data ',data)
if(false){
   var data ='ppp';
}
}
```

Comment: maybe add a space after the =

Comment: Because you have defined `data` again...  And due to function scope you have 2 vars called data.

Comment: This is a hoisting effect, this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript) might be very interesting to you.

Comment: Thank you guys for useful info